# Rails change default layout and view path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I can't do

```
 render :action => '/apps/apptype/theme/content/index',
        :layout => '/apps/apptype/theme/layout'
```

How i can add new layout and action path ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about what you are trying, but you can specify the layout for a specific action, modify your index action to this:

**This uses the default folder for layouts views/layouts**

```
def index 
    render(:layout => "your-layout-name")
end
```

If you just want to render a template in that path, you can use :template instead of :layout

```
def index
     render(:template => "/apps/apptype/theme/layout/your-layout-name")
end
```

Comment: When i do this rails returns Missing template error

Comment: I forgot that the default folder for layouts is views/layouts.. So, you must move your layout file to that folder and then just call in your render (post updated)

Comment: Can you add more details what are you trying to achieve here? That way we can help you figure out

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for hours for a solution nothing really helped until I found this. For me it worked after I override an abstract method in my controller. The original abstract method is :

`def _normalize_layout(value)
  value.is_a?(String) && value !~ /\blayouts/ ? "layouts/#{value}" : value
end`

Just add a method like this in your controller:

```
def _normalize_layout(value)
value =~ /yourpath/ ? value : "layouts/#{value}"
end
```

I only tested it with a path like '/_pages/'. After this I could do:

```
layout '/_pages/example/test/resources/views/_layout'
```

And it worked!

Don't ask me how the changed method really works, I'm not a pro in this. But I would appreciate if someone can explain.

Source: https://www.garbageburrito.com/blog/entry/3156653/putting-your-layouts-in-a-non-layouts-directory-in-rails

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by setting template path to html and layout to layout

```
render (:template  => '/apps/apptype/theme/content/index',
        :layout => '/apps/apptype/theme/layout')
```